# How can you allocate a multidimensional array of the same size as another already allocated array in fortran without adopting the same values?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a setup that looks as following:

```
real(pReal), dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: &
    first_array, &
    second_array

first_array = custom_array_generating_function()
```

I would like to assign the same shape as `first_array` to `second_array`, but not the same values. Something like

```
allocate(second_array, mold=first_array)
second_array = 0_pReal
```

would work, but then I would need to overwrite all the values this array was initialized with, which is not ideal.

The following approaches also didn't work:

```
allocate(second_array(shape(first_array),source=0_pReal)
allocate(second_array(size(first_array(1)),size(first_array(2)),size(first_array(3))),source=0_pReal)
allocate(second_array(shape(first_array)(1),size(first_array)(2),size(first_array)(3)),source=0_pReal)
```

Is there a standardized way of accomplishing this?

Comment: You aren't overwriting any values of `second_array`: that allocation doesn't define any part of the array, just its shape.

Comment: I was initially under the impression that using the `mold` statement would essentially copy both the shape and the values of the target expression, which I see now is not the case. Does this mean that initializing the values of `second_array` like this is already the best way to copy the shape of another array and use different values?

Comment: To get the extents of `first_array` you must use `size(first_array,1)` not `size(first_array(1))`. This second is asking for the size of an element of the array, which is `0` (it's a scalar)

Comment: Now it's not clear that there is a question left here.  The suggested `allocate(second_array, mold=first_array)` looks like a perfectly acceptable way of answering the question title.  If writing two lines of code is too much for you, perhaps `allocate(second_array, source=0.0*first_array)` would appeal? (I haven't checked this works, no Fortran on this machine.)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark AFAIK `source` cannot replace `mold`. The correct syntax would be `allocate(second_array, mold=first_array, source=0.0_pReal)`

Comment: Well, as I wrote, I'm flying by the seat of my pants here, no Fortran compiler to hand.  and my understanding of the language spec is that a single `allocate` statement can't have both `mold` and `source` arguments.

Comment: @PierU You can't have `source` and `mold` in the same allocate expression (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xffbg/121.141?topic=attributes-allocate)

Comment: My bad then, I was almost sure it was possible...

Comment: `allocate(second_array, source=0.0*first_array)` may appeal, but it shouldn't. Not only is it a complicated way of writing `second_array=0*first_array` it doesn't necessarily give `second_array` the same bounds as `first_array`.